# Como fazer um "LIKE" numa consulta DJANGO ORM?

Tags: mysql, python, django, orm

Para fazer uma consulta para pegar os dados com exatidão no Django, eu utilizo o `filter`, dessa forma:

```
usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome='Jonh')
```

Isso vai gerar uma SQL parecida com:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios wHERE nome = 'Jonh'
```

Como estou usando Django a pouco tempo, gostaria de saber no caso como é que eu faria para fazer um `LIKE`.

O Banco de dados que eu estou utilizado é o Mysql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de executar essa consulta:

**Case sensitive**

1. Utilizando o [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains): 
   `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__contains='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE '%Jonh%';`
2. Utilizando o [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith): `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__startswith='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE 'Jonh%';`
3. Utilizando o [`endswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#endswith): `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__endswith='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE '%Jonh';`

**Case insensitive**

1. Utilizando o [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains): 
   `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__icontains='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome ILIKE '%Jonh%';`
2. Utilizando o [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith): `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__istartswith='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome ILIKE 'Jonh%';`
3. Utilizando o [`iendswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#iendswith): `usuarios = Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__iendswith='Jonh')`

   - SQL: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome ILIKE '%Jonh';`

A utilização do double underscore (__), definida pela constante [`LOOKUP_SEP`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/db/models/constants.py) é utilizada pela ORM - object-relational mapping - para a geração das consultas SQL, separando a variável do comando de pesquisa, como no exemplo do LIKE: `nome__iendswith='Jonh'` interpretado para `nome ILIKE 'Jonh%'`.

Comment: Acredito que as duas situações que você indicou o `endswith` estão com um erro no posicionamento do `%`. Visto que o `%` indica qualquer coisa àquele lado, então nessas partes, ele deveria estar à esquerda do termo procurado, não à direita. Se eu estiver errado, desconsidere.

Comment: copiar colar, ajustei, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Eu pesquisei um pouco e achei [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731675/mysql-like-in-django-python) resposta aqui.

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Usuarios.objects.filter(nome__contains = "Jonh")
```

E segundo a própria resposta, o `__contains` é case sensitive, podendo ser usado o `__icontains` para ignorar o case (maiúscula/minuscula)

Comment: Interessante. Sempre que eu quiser usar uma "funcionalidade" eu preciso colocar essa undescore dupla?

Comment: Não tenho ideia, Eu apenas pesquisei e achei essa resposta.

Comment: A underscore dupla é a forma que o ORM do Django encontrou de permitir colocar o nome do operador direto como parâmetro para uma chamada - do outro lado (dentro do código do django), ele faz um "split("__"), qyue quebrao nome do parâmetro em dois - a primeira parte tem o nome do campo, e a segunda o nome do operador)

Comment: o SQLAlchemy, o ORM mais popular pra Python, faz isso de forma diferente: ele sobrecarrega os operadores (`==`, `>=`,  `in`, etc)... dos objetos que são os campos nas tabelas - então em vez de  simplesmente fazer a operação, o Python gera um objeto que é usado para montar a query SQL.   Mas nesse caso, ficaria algo assim `...query().filter("John" in Usuarios.nome).all `

Comment: @jsbueno sensacional, cara. Muito obrigado